# Running Image magick code after installation

Tags: php, imagemagick, centos, imagick

I have just installed Imagemagick and imagick in my centos .using

```
yum install ImageMagick
yum install ImageMagick-devel

cd /root
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/imagick-3.0.1.tgz
tar zxf imagick-3.0.1.tgz
cd imagick-3.0.1
phpize
./configure
make
make install
```

Installation went fine without any errors , but now iam trying to run, php ImageMagick code

```
<?php  
$cmd = " -background none -pointsize 60 -font DRAGM.ttf -fill red ". 
 " -strokewidth 1 -stroke black label:\"myexample\" "; 

exec("convert $cmd coloured_font.png"); 
?>
```

**Edit:** I have also tried this code... but still it's displaying a blank page...

```
<?php
/* Create some objects */
$image = new Imagick();
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$pixel = new ImagickPixel( 'gray' );

/* New image */
$image->newImage(800, 75, $pixel);

/* Black text */
$draw->setFillColor('black');

/* Font properties */
$draw->setFont('Bookman-DemiItalic');
$draw->setFontSize( 30 );

/* Create text */
$image->annotateImage($draw, 10, 45, 0, 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog');

/* Give image a format */
$image->setImageFormat('png');

/* Output the image with headers */
header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $image;
```

php.info shows

**imagick module**  enabled
        **imagick module version**  3.0.1
        **imagick classes** Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel, ImagickPixelIterator
        **ImageMagick version** ImageMagick 6.5.4-7 2012-05-07 Q16 OpenMP http://www.imagemagick.org
        **ImageMagick copyright**   Copyright (C) 1999-2009 ImageMagick Studio LLC
        **ImageMagick release date**    2012-05-07
        **ImageMagick number of supported formats:**    198
        **ImageMagick supported formats**   A, AI, ART, ARW, AVI, AVS, B, BGR, BMP, BMP2, BMP3, BRF, BRG, C, CALS, CAPTION, CIN, CIP, CLIP, CMYK, CMYKA, CR2, CRW, CUR, CUT, DCM, DCR, DCX, DDS, DFONT, DNG, DOT, DPS, DPX, EPDF, EPI, EPS, EPS2, EPS3, EPSF, EPSI, EPT, EPT2, EPT3, ERF, FAX, FITS, FRACTAL, FTS, G, G3, GBR, GIF, GIF87, GRADIENT, GRAY, GRB, HALD, HISTOGRAM, HRZ, HTM, HTML, ICB, ICO, ICON, INFO, INLINE, IPL, ISOBRL, JNG, JP2, JPC, JPEG, JPG, JPX, K, K25, KDC, LABEL, M, M2V, M4V, MAP, MAT, MATTE, MIFF, MNG, MONO, MOV, MP4, MPC, MPEG, MPG, MRW, MSL, MSVG, MTV, MVG, NEF, NULL, O, ORF, OTB, OTF, PAL, PALM, PAM, PATTERN, PBM, PCD, PCDS, PCL, PCT, PCX, PDB, PDF, PDFA, PEF, PFA, PFB, PFM, PGM, PGX, PICON, PICT, PIX, PJPEG, PLASMA, PNG, PNG24, PNG32, PNG8, PNM, PPM, PREVIEW, PS, PS2, PS3, PSD, PTIF, PWP, R, RADIAL-GRADIENT, RAF, RAS, RBG, RGB, RGBA, RGBO, RLA, RLE, SCR, SCT, SFW, SGI, SHTML, SR2, SRF, STEGANO, SUN, SVG, SVGZ, TEXT, TGA, THUMBNAIL, TIFF, TIFF64, TILE, TIM, TTC, TTF, TXT, UBRL, UIL, UYVY, VDA, VICAR, VID, VIFF, VST, WBMP, WMF, WMV, WMZ, WPG, X, X3F, XBM, XC, XCF, XPM, XPS, XV, XWD, Y, YCbCr, YCbCrA, YUV

ideally it should create image with the text `myexample`, but its not working, is there any ways to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried `php -m` to see if the extension is enabled at all?

Comment: i checked, its showing as `imagic` but not showing for `imagemagick` does it has to show?

Comment: Hm... I think that you are using a "_wrong_" approach. You are using the plain old command instead of the PHP extension classes to generate the image. Is that intended? If you use the command, you don't need the PHP extension at all.

Comment: actually i need to work on php extension class, for some image manipulations...thats the reason iam trying this method , and ideally it should work but not sure whats the bug here :(

Comment: @Dolly the OP is not using Windows, and the used method is "fine" as long as it does load the PHP extension, as shown by `php -m`.

Comment: Hello Dolly, The link what u have given its for `wndows ` but iam using `centos`

Comment: @Friend the code you shown is working on my setup. Do a `phpinfo` and check for the extension, just in case your webserver is not loading it.

Comment: hi  Diego Agulló, i have checked phpinfo, please check my updated question,it is showing.........

Comment: Check the logs to see if it's dropping some error. Use (for instance) chrome developer tools to check whether the script is sending a `image/png` response.

Comment: I checked but i think its not showing anything please check this link where i have put the above code (myexample) http://www.srihost.com/im.php and this is my http://www.srihost.com/info.php phpinfo pageplease let me know if u can find any bugs..

Comment: DO WE HAVE TO INSTALL/CONFIGURE SUPHP?TORUN IM CODE THROUGH PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your "-font DRAGM.ttf".
Try to set OR "/full/path/to/font.ttf", OR just font name.
Available list of font names:
"convert -list font" from console.

Comment: hmm sorry  did not mention, i have already tried `-font Times-Roman`

Comment: Does string "Font: Times-Roman" present in output of "convert -list font"?